# How to get concrete class from JSON response?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a basic JAVA class:

```
public class BasicDefinition {

    private Integer id = null;
    private String name = null;

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to parse web service response in my JAVA server using Jackson, the service response matching my class,  I'm using the following command to get my result from server:

```
String resultString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

the resultString is:

```
{GetBasicEntityDefinitionsResult={ID=1, Name=Some Name}}
```

How can I convert the string to return my class? my function gets T as the class that need to be returned. in this case, T is BasicDefinition

Comment: mapper.readValue(json, BasicDefinition.class), where mapper = new ObjectMapper()

Comment: {GetBasicEntityDefinitionsResult={ID=1, Name=Some Name}} is not json

Answer (score 0):

Use jackson Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'xyz'}";

//JSON from file to Object

className obj = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\file.json"), className.class);

Answer (score -1):

You can do it.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{ID=1, Name=Some Name}";
BasicDefinition bd = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, BasicDefinition.class);
```

Comment: Have you tested your code before posting? Are you sure you won't get any exceptions? `{ID=1, Name=Some Name}` is not a valid JSON.

Comment: I did not test that json before, I only took the json posted by the author of the topic.